# How to search something on a complex NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have a `NSMutableArray`. It has 8 objects. Each object has 5 key value pairs like this

```
{
    "Attendance": {}, 
    "Shift": {}, 
    "DayType": {}, 
    "DayTypes": null, 
    "TotalOvertimeString": "06:00"
},
```

and this "Attendance" also another dictionary. It is like this

```
"Attendance": {
        "AttendanceCode": 5058, 
        "Date": "2016-02-01T00:00:00", 
        "EmployeeCode": 2941, 
        "ShiftCode": 1, 
        "DayTypeCode": 1, 
        "Expected": true, 
        "Midnight": false, 
        "Present": true, 
        "InTime": "2016-02-01T08:00:00", 
        "InTimeString": "08:00", 
        "OutTime": "2016-02-01T20:00:00", 
        "OutTimeString": "20:00", 
        "OutDate": "2016-02-01T00:00:00", 
        "InTime2": "1901-01-01T00:00:00", 
        "InTime2String": "00:00", 
        "InDate2": "1901-01-01T00:00:00", 
        "OutTime2": "1901-01-01T00:00:00", 
        "OutTime2String": "00:00", 
        "OutDate2": "1901-01-01T00:00:00", 
        "ApprovedOutTimeUsed": 0, 
        "ApprovedOutTime": "1901-01-01T00:00:00", 
        "Late": 0, 
        "LateString": "00:00", 
        "InLate": 0, 
        "InLateString": "00:00", 
        "MidLate": 0, 
        "MidLateString": "", 
        "OutLate": 0, 
        "OutLateString": "00:00", 
        "InOvertime": 0, 
        "InOvertimeString": "", 
        "OvertimeRate1": 6, 
        "OvertimeRate1String": "06:00", 
        "OvertimeRate1Approved": 0, 
        "OvertimeRate1ApprovedString": "00:00", 
        "OvertimeRate2": 0, 
        "OvertimeRate2String": "00:00", 
        "OvertimeRate2Approved": 0, 
        "OvertimeRate2ApprovedString": "00:00", 
        "OvertimeRate3": 0, 
        "OvertimeRate3String": "00:00", 
        "OvertimeRate3Approved": 0, 
        "OvertimeRate3ApprovedString": "00:00", 
        "OvertimeRate4": 0, 
        "OvertimeRate4String": "00:00", 
        "OvertimeRate4Approved": 0, 
        "OvertimeRate4ApprovedString": "00:00", 
        "OvertimeRate5": 0, 
        "OvertimeRate5String": "00:00", 
        "OvertimeRate5Approved": 0, 
        "OvertimeRate5ApprovedString": "00:00", 
        "OvertimeRate6": 0, 
        "OvertimeRate6String": "00:00", 
        "OvertimeRate6Approved": 0, 
        "OvertimeRate6ApprovedString": "00:00", 
        "OvertimeApprovalDone": false, 
        "Lieu": false, 
        "LieuFirstTaken": false, 
        "LieuSecondTaken": false, 
        "LieuPayment": 0, 
        "DayOff": false, 
        "DayOffTaken": false, 
        "LeaveTypeCode": 0, 
        "LeaveAmount": 0, 
        "LeaveTypeCode2": 0, 
        "LeaveAmount2": 0, 
        "ShortLeaveAmount": 0, 
        "Premium": 0, 
        "PremiumString": "00:00", 
        "PremiumApproved": 0, 
        "PremiumApprovedString": "00:00", 
        "Missing": 0, 
        "MissingString": "00:00", 
        "ClockNumber": 0, 
        "SectionCode": 0, 
        "WorkHours": 0, 
        "PeriodWorked": 0, 
        "WorkHrs": 0, 
        "Remarks": "uuuuuuuuuuuuuuus", 
        "Deleted": false, 
        "Status": true, 
        "CreatedBy": 0, 
        "CreatedDate": "1901-01-01T00:00:00", 
        "UpdatedBy": 9, 
        "UpdatedDate": "2016-01-13T22:48:03.737", 
        "DeletedBy": 0, 
        "DeletedDate": "1901-01-01T00:00:00"
    },
```

What I want to do is find this exact date value is available or not in this Array `"Date": "2016-02-01T00:00:00"`How I can search whether this date is available or not in this Array? Please help me.

Comment: Since you know the structure of the element of the array, you can traverse all the element in a array with many methods, for example,`enumerateObjectsUsingBlock`. And If your goal is to find a convenient way to judge whether the date is available in the whole array, I suggest you convert the array in to a JSON string, and you can treat it like a long string, and it's easy to find the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `valueForKeyPath` instead of `valueForKey` for this kind of nested structure. This first object is a dictionary.

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{
    @"Attendance": @{...,@"Date": @"2016-02-01T00:00:00",....}, 
    @"Shift": @{}, 
    @"DayType": @{}, 
    @"TotalOvertimeString": @"06:00"
};
```

Use the below line of code:

```
[[dict valueForKeyPath:@"Attendance.Date"] isEqualToString:@"your date"]
```

Comment: so I need to use a for loop?

Comment: If you already know the name of the key in first object i.e. Attendance, then there is no need for any loop. And if you don't know the key name you need to use the loop only for the outer dictionary that contains 8 dictionary objects.

Comment: But how to travel for every 8 object? coz I have {
    "Attendance": {}, 
    "Shift": {}, 
    "DayType": {}, 
    "DayTypes": null, 
    "TotalOvertimeString": "06:00"
},  this type of 8 objects.

Comment: I had to use enumerateObjectsUsingBlock also to get the output

Comment: You can use a for-in loop to enumerate over the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Try below line of code 
[arrray valueForKey @"Attendance"]valueForKey@"Date"]isEqualToString:@"2016-02-01T00:00:00" ]

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get data from it and compare in the following way.

```
NSMutableArray *array = @[];//Array of dictionaries
NSDate *dateToCompare = [NSDate date];//Any date you want to compare
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in array) {
    NSDate *dateAttendance = dictionary[@"Attendance"][@"Date"];
    //Compare dates
    if ([dateToCompare isEqualToDate:dateAttendance]) {
        NSLog(@"Dates equal");
    }
}
```

If both dates are in NSString you can use

```
[dateToCompareString isEqualToString:dateAttendanceString]
```

Comment: So still I need to use a foor loop? because I have like 8 objects in my Array

Comment: In that case you can use for loop

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this

```
([yourArray@[0] valueForKey@"Date"] compare:dateYouEntered == NSOrderedSame)
```

then date you entered is exists in yourArray

Answer (score 0):

worked on @Muhammad Nabeel Arif answer. U just need to iterate all your objects in ur NSMutableArray get all dates in an array. At last u can check for your date using containsObject method of NSMutableArray.

```
NSDate *dateToCompare = [NSDate date];//Any date you want to compare
NSMutableArray *allDates =[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i = 0; i<array.count; i++)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = @{};//YOur data
    NSDate *dateAttendance = dictionary[@"Attendance"][@"Date"];//Compare dates
    [allDates addObject:dateAttendance];
}

if([allDates containsObject:dateToCompare])
{
// Do whatever if it exists
}else
   {
`// place your code here if its doesnt exist.`
   }
```

containsObject method returns YES if anObject is present in the array, otherwise NO.

Hope it helps. Happy Coding..!!